# Can't send post request in Postman

Tags: curl, postman

```
curl --request POST 'https://eth.getblock.io/mainnet/' \
--header 'x-api-key: 08c935d3-15a9-4cab-a9cc-c86cd1c9c869' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"method": "eth_getBlockByNumber",
"params": ["0x68B3", true],
"id": "getblock.io"}'
```

Hi guys. I have one problem with mu request in Postman

This curl works, but I need send this request with its parameters in Postman. I do this and when eventually I see **"upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure"**

I'm expecting an output of my request in Postman without this error. Thanks fro advance

Comment: If your problem is with postman do NOT abuse the system and slap every conceivable tag on your question. Assign it only such tags as are relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

### Import your curl

Select Import then Raw Text and paste in the curl like this:

[image: Postman Import]